# Setting a 4x4 Rotation Matrix using Degrees

Tags: c++, math, matrix

I would like to ask what the steps are to setting a 4x4 Rotation Matrix using degrees for all separate X, Y, Z axis.

Illustrations would be much appreciated, thanks!

(C++ implementation preferred)

Comment: Did you consider using google? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: Do you have an implementation in some programming language in mind?

Comment: I tried Wikipedia, perhaps I did not thoroughly go through it, but there was not a clear illustration for setting up a 4x4 rotational matrix. Preferably in C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compose a rotation matrix with human readable angles from scratch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075743/how-do-i-compose-a-rotation-matrix-with-human-readable-angles-from-scratch)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a C++ program, if you want a header-only library that will do this for you, you can use the amazing glm:

http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/index.html

And use `glm::rotate` as such:

```
glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.f);
glm::mat4 ViewTranslate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -Translate));
glm::mat4 ViewRotateX = glm::rotate(ViewTranslate, Rotate.y, glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
glm::mat4 View = glm::rotate(ViewRotateX, Rotate.x, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
glm::mat4 Model = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.5f));
glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model;
```

You can find the implementation on Github if you are interested in writing your own: [matrix_transform.inl](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/78f686b4be6c623df829db58b974bf8d79461987/glm/gtc/matrix_transform.inl)